# How to change Nvidia X server settings?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, nvidia, settings

In Ubuntu 11.04, graphics settings for the driver could be found under "System Settings".

In Ubuntu 11.10, the "System Settings" menu has been scaled down considerably. Now I do not know how to access these settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until you find a better option, just run

```
nvidia-settings
```

From a terminal or the run dialogue.

**Edit:** I'm using the old panels-based system and I just found its link sitting in a group called "Other" under Applications. No idea how that's translated in Unity but it should be in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. This works. *sigh* I do like the 11.04 system settings menu more with the expanded customization though. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, click on the Dash Home button and type "nv" in the search line.  The Nvidia X Server Settings will be displayed.